# define variable of global scope in local scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, polling

I am working in javascript. I am trying to  reload the page when user is logged in.  I am  polling to constantly check user data.  Find the codes the below

```
var check;
 function poll(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/poll',
            type:'GET',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
        }).done(function(data){
              console.log(data); //  if user is logged in ,server sends the user object else it doesn't
              if(typeof data.name !== "undefined"){
                  check = '1';   // Browser doesnt remember check was 1 after reload
                  window.location.reload();
                    } else
                    {
                        setTimeout(function(){ poll(); }, 5000);
                    }


                });
    }

    if(typeof check == 'undefined'){     // Problem is here on reload, browser doesnt remember that i set `check = 1` in above condition. 
    setTimeout(function(){ poll(); }, 5000);
    }
```

I am trying to make workflow like ,

1) If user is not logged in , polling should continue. It should keep checking the wheather user is logged in or not .

2) If user is logged in , Reload page automatically and polling stops

Comment: replace "window.parent.check" by "check" ?, but if you reload the page, the entire js is reload. Should reload the page with a GET parameter

Comment: Why do you use `window.parent.check`? this would only be useful in combination with an `iframe` but as you don't mention anything about an `iframe` you might have a misunderstanding of what `window.parent` is used for. Even with an `iframe` the code does not make much sens.

Comment: @Hacketo I tried "check" but not working , I was looking for a way topass some paramter on reload function  but no success . I removes window.parent.check to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local storage (HTML5) of browser or cookies.

Comment: I can't use server side. Is it possible in client side?

Comment: @NeiL: Have you actually read the answer? It doesn't suggest to use the server.